# Future<Widget> can't be assigned to the list type 'widget'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm making a dialog screen which contains a dropbox and list view like below.

```
showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext DialogContext, StateSetter setState) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Dropdown(DialogContext, setState, 0, ReceiveArgs, _lListOfDepthList), 
                    Dropdown(DialogContext, setState, 1, ReceiveArgs, _lListOfDepthList),                        
                    FutureListView(ReceiveArgs),                                            
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        });
```

Since I called `SetName`, which returns a Future, I needed to change 'FutureListView' to a Future function too.

```
  Future<Widget> FutureListView(ArgumentClass ReceiveArgs) async{
    String SelectedFullAddress = GetSelectedAddress(5, "");

    _Name = await SetName(ReceiveArgs.lFullList, SelectedFullAddress);

    if (_Name.isNotEmpty) {
      print("ListView!");
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _Name.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text(_Name[index]),
            value: null,
            onChanged: null,
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      print("List Null");
      return Text("");
    }
  }
```

However after the change, I get this error at compile time:

> error: The element type 'Future' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'. (list_element_type_not_assignable at [checker_v2])

How do I provide a Future to the List which expects only Widgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `FutureBuilder`.

Here's how your `FutureListView` should look like (you can change the name of the method now)

```dart
 Future<String> FutureListView(ArgumentClass ReceiveArgs) async{
        String SelectedFullAddress = GetSelectedAddress(5, "");
  
        return await SetName(ReceiveArgs.lFullList, SelectedFullAddress);
      }
```

And, this should be your showDialog

```dart
showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext DialogContext, StateSetter setState) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Dropdown(DialogContext, setState, 0, ReceiveArgs, _lListOfDepthList),
                    Dropdown(DialogContext, setState, 1, ReceiveArgs, _lListOfDepthList),
                    FutureBuilder<String>(
                    future: FutureListView(ReceiveArgs),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) => {
                      if(!snapshot.hasData) return Container(); // This container can be a loading screen, since its waiting for data.

                      if(snapshot.data.isNotEmpty){
                        print("ListView!");
                        return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: _Name.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return CheckboxListTile(
                              title: Text(_Name[index]),
                              value: null,
                              onChanged: null,
                              );
                            },
                          );,
                        } else {
                          print("List Null");
                          return Text("");
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        });
```

FutureBuilder's future **won't** wait until the async method is completed, but try to build the builder method until it is. You can use `snapshot.hasData` to check if the async method has returned something already, and if it doesn't, you can show a loading screen if you want. Then, use `snapshot.data` to access the result of your future.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap widget with `Future` to `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
FutureBuilder<TypeOfName>(
  future: getName(),
  builder (context, snapshot) {
    // Data is not loading, you should show progress indicator to user
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    // Data from Future is loaded
    final name = snapshot.data;
    if (name.isEmpty) {
      return Text('');
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: name.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text(name[index]),
            value: null,
            onChanged: null,
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
);
```

And `getName()` method:

```dart
Future<TypeOfName> getName() {
  String SelectedFullAddress = GetSelectedAddress(5, "");
  return SetName(ReceiveArgs.lFullList, SelectedFullAddress);
}
```

And replace `TypeOfName` for type of `_Name` variable (you cannot declare it).

Comment: Thank you! I got a hint from you too and I solve my problem! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a type Widget instead of Future because you can't call a future directly inside a widget design.

You can simply modify your code like this.

```
  Widget FutureListView(ArgumentClass receiveArgs) {
    String SelectedFullAddress = GetSelectedAddress(5, "");
    _Name = await SetName(receiveArgs.lFullList, SelectedFullAddress);
    if (_Name.isNotEmpty) {
    bool _isChecked = false;

    print("ListView!");
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 3,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return  CheckboxListTile(
            value: _isChecked,
            title: Text(_Name[index]),
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                _isChecked = value;
              });
            },
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      print("List Null");
      return Text("");
    }
  }
```